# JavaScript function not called on page load

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have a JavaScript function placed at the bottom of my page but for some reason the page isn't called on page load. I tried running it on console to be sure it doesn't produce an error, but it ran perfectly fine. I even tried setting the

```
window.onload = function() {applyMovement();}
```

That didn't even work.

about.js

```
function applyMovement() {
    let bars = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar');
    for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
        moveBar(bars[i], i);
    }
}
```

index.blade.php

```
...
</body>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/about.js') }}">window.onload = function() {applyMovement();} </script>
</html>
```

It should be noted that I am using Laravel 5.8. I've placed my JS file inside the public directory. Also other actions on the file are being ran but not this patricular function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing a new script tag under the declaration of about.js. Like so:

```
...
</body>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/about.js') }}"> </script>
<script> window.onload = function() {applyMovement();} </script>
</html>
```

If that didnt work, try the following (bind it to window as a global):

```
window.applyMovement = function() {
    let bars = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar');
    for (let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
        moveBar(bars[i], i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help .